# Preventing insertion of overlapping date ranges using using days of the week and tsrange

Tags: php, postgresql

I hope I'll explain it well.

My table has the following structure

```
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 name      | text    |           |          |         | extended |              |
 days_week | text    |           |          |         | extended |              |
 datetime  | tsrange |           |          |         | extended |              |
Indexes:
"test_name_datetime_excl" EXCLUDE USING gist (name WITH =, datetime WITH &&)
```

I have been trying to insert the same date and time for the same name but only changing the days_week. I know something is missing on the structure of my table but I just don't know what.
This is the sample of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Insert into test values (‘first name’,’ Monday’, ‘[2020-01-01 08:30, 2020-01-01 10:00)’);
INSERT 0 1

Insert into test values (‘first name’,’ Monday’, ‘[2020-01-01 08:30, 2020-01-01 10:00)’);  this will be a error or conflicts with existing key

Insert into test values (‘first name’,’ Monday’, ‘[2020-01-01 10:00, 2020-01-01 10:30)’);
INSERT 0 1

Insert into test values (‘first name’,’ Tuesday’, ‘[2020-01-01 08:30, 2020-01-01 10:00)’);
INSERT 0 1

Insert into test values (‘second name’,’ Monday’, ‘[2020-01-01 08:30, 2020-01-01 10:00)’);
INSERT 0 1

Insert into test values (‘second name’,’ Monday’, ‘[2020-01-01 08:30, 2020-01-01 10:00)’);  this will be a error or conflicts with existing key

Insert into test values (‘second name’,’ tuesday’, ‘[2020-01-01 08:30, 2020-01-01 10:00)’);
INSERT 0 1
```

I hope I explained it well.
Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is not well formed, try to add the error message you are facing, be much more specific and more granular about what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you just want to add `days_week` to the excluding index:

```
create table test (
    name text,
    days_week text,
    datetime tsrange,
    exclude using gist (name with =, days_week with =, datetime with &&)
)
```

This forbids overlapping ranges on the same `name` and `days_week`, while allowing other cases.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=faacfb1c411bde2ccec57663ac50988f)**